# Linear Algebra - "Closest" Solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a combination of vectors (alpha and beta unrestricted):

$ \gamma = \alpha\begin{pmatrix}
  3 \\
  2  \\
 5 \\
 \end{pmatrix} + \beta \begin{pmatrix}
  6 \\
  1  \\
 2 \\
 \end{pmatrix} $

and an associated value

$\lambda = 19\alpha + 13\beta$

I want to maximise $\lambda$ such that $\gamma \le \begin{pmatrix}
  33 \\
  9  \\
 19 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

I want to minimise $\lambda$ such that $\gamma \ge \begin{pmatrix}
  33 \\
  9  \\
 19 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$

*The context here is asset pricing, but felt this would be more suited as a maths question as that's what it boils down to.*

Does anyone have any methods that work well?

Comment: What do you mean by a variable "greater than or equal to" or "less than or equal to" a matrix?

Comment: Probably they mean entry-wise.

Comment: I thought that was standard notation for entry-wise as Casteels says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems are really standard linear programs. I'm going to write $x$ for $\alpha$ and $y$ for $\beta$.
The first problem is:

> maximize $19x+13y$ subject to:
>
> \begin{eqnarray}
> 3x+6y&\leq 33\\
> 2x+ y&\leq 9\\
> 5x+2y&\leq 19
> \end{eqnarray}

Notice the three inequalities define half-planes, and you could easily draw out the region of feasible solutions by hand, or join us in the year $2015$ and ask [Wolfram to do so for you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%2019x%2B13y%20subject%20to%203x%2B6y%3C%3D33%2C%202x%2By%3C%3D9%2C%205x%2B2y%3C%3D19). Since your objective function $19x+13y=\lambda$ is a line with a negative slope, the optimal solution ends up occurring at that single vertex in the region of feasible solutions, which turns out to be the intersection of the lines $3x+6y=33$ and $5x+2y=19$. This intersection point is $(2,\frac{9}{2})$, and so $\lambda=\frac{193}{2}$. You can [verify this also with  Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%2019x%2B13y%20subject%20to%203x%2B6y%3C%3D33%2C%202x%2By%3C%3D9%2C%205x%2B2y%3C%3D19)

The second program is

> minimize $19x+13y$ subject to:
>
> \begin{eqnarray}
> 3x+6y&\geq 33\\
> 2x+ y&\geq 9\\
> 5x+2y&\geq 19
> \end{eqnarray}

Again you can just ask Wolfram to do this for you, [getting an answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize%2019x%2B13y%20subject%20to%203x%2B6y%3E%3D33%2C%202x%2By%3E%3D9%2C%205x%2B2y%3E%3D19) of $(x,y)=(\frac{7}{3},\frac{13}{3})$ where $\lambda= \frac{302}{3}.$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The Wolfram alpha comments aren't helpful - of course that's a solution.